# Python .txt file not reading correctly

Tags: python-3.x

I have been started to have a look at using .txt files in my code but when I use these lines of code it just brings back this,
 `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='names.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`

Here is the code I am using:

```
f = open('names.txt','r')
f.read()
print(f)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store result of `file.read()` to variable, and then print the variable.

For example:

```
f = open('names.txt','r')
data = f.read()
print(data)
f.close()
```

---

You can also use `with` keyword to not close the file explicitly:

```
with open('names.txt','r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```